# React Native Render Modal onMessage Firebase Notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have registered an `onMessage()` Firebase Notification Listener in a Service class (not a React Component) in my app.

Inside the method I'm invoking a React Component that renders a Modal. Problem is that the Component is never invoked (I tried adding debug statement in `constructor()` and `render()` methods of the Component but they are not printed.

Here is my listener code:

```
this.notificationListener = messaging().onMessage(async notification => {
    console.log("listener is invoked"); //this is printed.
    <MyModalComponent />
}
```

Updated Class code based on Riwen's comment:

```
class NotificationService extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           dummy: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(<></>);
    }

    async registerNotifications() {
        await this.checkPermissions();

        this.registerNotificationsListeners();
    }

    registerNotificationsListeners() {
        this.notificationListener = messaging().onMessage(async notification => {
            console.log('there is a notification ', notification); //this gets printed
            this.setState({dummy: true});
            {this.state.dummy && <MyModalComponent />}
        }
    }
}

<NotificationService />
```

Component is still not invoked.

Comment: Listen to the event from a component, set the state when it fires, display the modal when the state has been changed.

Comment: Thanks. I just converted my class to a Component but it is still not invoked, please see the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class NotificationService extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           dummy: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(<>{this.state.dummy && <MyModalComponent />}</>);
    }

    registerNotificationsListeners() {
        this.notificationListener = messaging().onMessage(async notification => {
            console.log('there is a notification ', notification); //this gets printed
            this.setState({dummy: true});
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure you actually register for notification listener, such as in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting this: `ERROR: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted` even though I have `<NotificationService />` at the end of that file (assuming that it should be mounted when the file is loaded in App.js).

Comment: @codebee where do you call `registerNotificationsListeners`?

Comment: Inside `NotiticationService.registerNotifications()`, please see code in updated post. Then I'm invoking that method in App.js -> `await NotificationService.registerNotifications();`

Comment: @codebee you shouldn't try to modify state until the component has been mounted. Instead, you should only register for any events in the appropriate lifecycle method (most of the cases, `componentDidMount`). Ideally, you should also unsubscribe before unmounting to avoid the same error as you've mentioned.